# Play! - max constraint doesn't work

Tags: constraints, playframework, max

I'm having a problem with my application and `@Max` constraint annotation.

My controller method is defined like this:

```
public static void save(@Required @Max(255) String content)
```

Later in my code I have error check:

```
if (Validation.hasErrors()) {
    render("Foo/bar.html", content);
}
```

The thing is, no matter what I post in the form (if it violates or not the constraint) I'm always getting error message that `Cannot be greater than 255`.

This is the text I'm, using for testing, 119 characters long:
*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ipsum enim, rhoncus eget volutpat at, posuere non eros.*

Anyone had similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you actually wanted to use [@MaxSize](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/validation-builtin#maxSize) to ensure that the length of the input was no more than 255.

Right now you're using [@Max](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/validation-builtin#max), which tries to convert the argument to a number to make sure it's numerically less than or equal to the given value. Your text can't be converted to a number, so the validation always fails in that case.